# Password Encrypt a file without needing recipient to have special software

Tags: encryption, zip, 7-zip

I need to send a zip file to a client and need to secure it with a password. I have tried WinZip, WinRAR, 7Zip and the Windows 10 built in encryption. All of them encrypt the file but on a machine without that software they cannot be unencrypted, in fact they give a cryptic error message.
I don't want my client to need special software to open this archive, though I am happy to buy something on my side. Is this even possible? Is there some way to make these products work in such a way that they can be opened with a password but no special software?

Comment: What's wrong with zip?  Windows supports it natively.

Comment: You can't specify a password when you try to encrypt.

Comment: Any time something is encrypted, a password is needed to decrypt it, otherwise nothing is accomplished.  It isn't clear why anything that offers encryption wouldn't work.

Comment: If your client uses a Mac then you can password protect an ISO that looks like an encrypted volume. Apple's Disk Utility will open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRAR can wrap its decompression function and your files into an executable. I guess your clients may not want to open a .exe file.

Another solution is to use a web storage service, like dropbox, where you can share a link to your zip file and set a fetch code.

Comment: I don't believe Dropbox offers a way to encrypt shared files.